# bash to prompt integers in terminal and get sum when entering =

Tags: bash, sum, echo, do-while

I'm looking for a rather simple solution to prompt integer numbers (one each line) into a terminal and in return for entering the equity-sign get all of them summed up.
I guess it has to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read X
read Y
echo " $ (( X + Y ) ) "
```

somehow I fail to amend it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if below script helps. If you have any questions, please let us know.

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
number='^[0-9]+$'
equal='='
while :
do
    read input
    if ! [[ $input =~ $number ]] && ! [[ $input =~ $equal ]] ; then
        echo -e "Please provide only numbers!"
    elif [[ $input =~ $equal ]] ; then
        echo -e "Sum : $sum"
        break   
    else
        let sum+=$input
    fi
done
```

**Sample Output**

```
10
201
2202 
2323
=
Sum : 4736
```

Comment: Glad to hear that, I've edited it to terminate after printing the sum.

Comment: perhaps you can give me a hint regarding the following, related question: I have another bash which contains an echo after a while-do-loop is done - for which case is this echo being executed at all? > # !/ bin / bash while ! test -f / tmp / stop ; do date sleep 1 done echo " halted ! "

Comment: @Maxito - The echo in the above script will be printed once a file named `/tmp/stop` exists.